# ¿Por que se ve una linea negra en el borde de la imagen?

Tags: c++, opengl

Estoy usando la imagen como una textura en glut, el problema es que se ven unas manchas negras en algunas imagenes cuando la imagen original es transparente.

Ejemplo, a la izquierda imagen original, a la derecha captura de glut con fondo cafe.

[image]

Estoy usando este codigo para cargar la imagen.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, tipo_imagen, textura->ancho(), textura->alto(), 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textura->imagen());

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Usando GL_NEAREST en lugar de GL_LINEAR no ocurre.

Nota: La imagen esta en formato tga y tiene un tamaño de 32x12 pixeles, porque en paginas como http://informatica.uv.es/iiguia/AIG/docs/texturas.htm dicen: "Las dimensiones de una textura deben ser siempre potencia de 2", si funciona igual. ¿puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que estaba configurado para que la textura se repitiera, y al aplicar el filtro `GL_LINEAR` influía el otro lado de la misma textura, con `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` evita que se repita la textura, por lo que soluciona el problema.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Con el filtro `GL_NEAREST` no ocurre porque no toma muestra de los pixeles cercanos como hace `GL_LINEAR`.

Mas información en: https://open.gl/textures